# Axis2 netbeans ClassNotFoundException NoClassDefFoundError creating web service

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, apache-axis

im looking for a light in this topic, I'm trying to generate a web service that uses different .jar, for example, gdata from google, jdom. And I cannot deploy this service on netbeans with axis2.

I'm using the plugin of netbeans, and creating the web service based in a existing .java

I've tried everything, (I created a web service when without refer clases in the jars), but when I involves clases from the jars (that I dont have the source code) axis, in the code or as a return element or parameter, throw me the error.

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

even though you have added libraries, your project is not able to find it appropriately.
Where you are adding your jars ??
You should add them at the classpath of your respective project.(lib folder)
Hope this will work.